# unable to create a nav tab link redirect to a new page

Tags: html, jquery

I read pretty much all related posts in order to find a solution to my simple problem, but with little success. I am trying to include a new page redirect from my li nav item.

```
<li
   class="nav-item d-flex col flex-grow-1 flex-shrink-0 mr-3 mb-3 mb-lg-0">
   <a class="nav-link border py-10 d-flex flex-grow-1 rounded flex-column align-items-center"
      data-toggle="pill" href="/topcontent.html">
      <span class="nav-text font-size-lg py-2 font-weight-bolder text-center">
      Top Content</span>
   </a>
</li>



<div class="tab-content m-0 p-0">
   <div class="tab-pane" id="forms_widget_tab_4" role="tabpanel"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried editing the top a href link to my file name: /report_1.html but it has not worked.

I have tried using jQuery to post a redirect but this has not worked either:

```
$('#my-div').click(function() {
   window.open('http://google.com');   
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am unable to resolve this.

Comment: I hardly understand what you mean. Kindly paste the actual code you are trying to use with the href attribute pointing to the url (report_1.html) and let's see the results.

Comment: I can hardly understand what you're saying.... '#my-div' which is given event listener 'click' is not specified in your html document. Did you mean to apply a click event to your li nav item in order to redirect to 'http://google.com'?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if this is fixing the issue you're posting in regard to, but I noticed that your href must have a typo:

```
href="#tab_forms_widget_4
```

which should be:

```
href="#forms_widget_tab_4
```

to match the id in div below, if you're trying to redirect the page to the element. Sorry if this isn't what you're looking for.